# Not change background or whole area (except statusBar)

Tags: flutter, dart

I  need to set status's bar background = orange and whole other area to blue color

snippet:

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                        top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                        right: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
                    child: new Text("TEST TEXT")))));
  }
}
```

result:

[image]

why blue background only for Text widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has occured as your container will only expand to *contain* whatever it has as a child.

You can use a media query to set the height and width of your container respective of your devices screen size.

The following code should achieve your desired effect:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(          
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Text("TEST TEXT"),
          ),          
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: This is what this code looks like]